# aws-sdk v3 dynamodb: binary data cannot be validated by joi anymore

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, joi

I have binary data stored in DynamoDB.
With aws-sdk v2 for javascript the binary data is returned in a format like this:

```
<Buffer 1b 85 23 00 2c 07 6c 63 12 d9 c7 ec 24 ea 89 ....
```

This can be validated by Joi using `joi.binary()`. Without updating my data in DynamoDB, using aws-sdk v3 my data looks like this when retrieved:

```
Uint8Array(1624) [
27, 133,  35,   0,  44,   7, 108,  99,  18, 217, 199, 236, ....
```

The rest of the application can handle the data without a problem only joi is not recognizing the data as binary anymore. I have tried to change the encoding setting in joi e.g. (`Joi.binary().encoding('base64');`) but I'm not sure what the correct one is.

How do I need to set my joi schema to make it work with the different data format?

Comment: AWS recommends storing blobs in S3 and persisting a path to the item on DynamoDB to access blobs

Comment: I am aware of that. The data was stored in dynamoDB intentionally for performance reasons.